# Create a data extension with nullable columns

Tags: soap-api, fuel-sdk, php, dataextensions

I'm trying to create a data extension with the [FuelSDK-PHP](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP), however I'm unable to create a column that has the property `Nullable`.

I've tried to do:

```
$de = new ET_DataExtension();
$de->authSub = $client;
$de->columns = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'date_birth',
        'FieldType' => 'Date',
        'IsRequired' => 'false',
        'IsNullable' => 'true'
    )
);
```

I've also tried to replace the `isNullable` to `Nullable`, however the column is still not nullable when created.

### EDIT

I'm also trying to create a column with the type `Decimal`:

```
array(
    'Name' => 'amount',
    'FieldType' => 'Decimal',
    'MaxLength' => '18,2'
)
```

I've also tried to replace the `MaxLength` with `Length` and `Scale`:

```
array(
    'Name' => 'amount',
    'FieldType' => 'Decimal',
    'Length' => '18',
    'Scale' => '2'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what's wrong!

### Nullable

To create a column nullable, the value must be `true` as a `boolean` and not as a `string`.

```
array(
    'Name' => 'date_birth',
    'FieldType' => 'Date',
    'IsNullable' => true
)
```

### Decimal

To create the decimal column with a length of `18,2`, we need to use `MaxLength` and `Scale` as `integers`:

```
array(
    'Name' => 'amount',
    'FieldType' => 'Decimal',
    'MaxLength' => 18,
    'Scale' => 2
)
```